# How can I stop a form repeating using fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, duplicates

I have a table of venues where each can have many offers.

I have a form which adds offers to venues from the venues edit page.

Once I submit the form the newly created offer is shown as a partial but instead of the form clearing to allow another offer to be entered, another form is created.

So if I enter 5 offers I have 6 add new offer forms, 5 of them with the details entered into the saved ones.

My code looks like this:

**venue model**

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :offers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:title].blank? }
end
```

**edit - venue controller**

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :only => [:update, :delete, :create] 
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    if
      @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).order("average_rating DESC").all
    else
      @venues = Venue.all
    end
    @venues = @venues.paginate :per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]
  end

  def new
    @venue = Venue.new
  end

  def create
    @venue = Venue.new params[:venue]
    if @venue.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Venue added'
      redirect_to venues_path
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    1.times { @venue.offers.build }
  end

  def update
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    @venue.attributes = params[:venue]
    if @venue.save!
      flash[:notice] = 'Venue updated successfully'
     redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def show
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def destroy
    Venue.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'Venue deleted successfully'
    redirect_to venues_path
  end
end
```

**venues edit.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
    <div class="edit_venue_details">

      <h2 class="venue_show_orange">Offers</h2>

      <% if @venue.offers.count.zero? %>
        <div class="no_reviews">
          No offers added yet.
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <%= render :partial => 'offers/offer', :collection => @venue.offers %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="clearall"></div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="edit_venue_sub_header">Add a new offer</h2>

    <%= f.fields_for :offers do |offer| %>
      <p class="edit_venue">title: <br>
      <%= offer.text_field :title, :class => "edit_venue_input" %></p>
    <% end %>
    <button class="submit_button" type="submit"> Save changes</button>
  <% end %>
```

How can I prevent a new form being created on submit?

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

**edit**

[image: no offers added]

[image: 1 offer added]

[image: 2 offers added]

Comment: Do new objects go to the edit action?

Comment: please show your entire controller

Comment: @Codeglot, thanks for having a look, I've edited my question.

Comment: ok. I thought you were using this: `redirect_to :back`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out for your controller:

```
def new
   @venue = Venue.new
   1.times { @venue.offers.build }
 end

 def create
   @venue = Venue.new params[:venue]
   if @venue.save
     flash[:notice] = 'Venue added'
     redirect_to edit_venue_path
   else
     render :action => :new
   end
 end

 def edit
   @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    1.times { @venue.offers.build }
 end

 def update
   @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
   if @venue.update_attributes(params[:venue])
     flash[:notice] = 'Venue updated successfully'
    redirect_to edit_venue_path(@venue)
   end
  end
```

Comment: that gives a undefined method `update_attributes=' for nil:NilClass error

Comment: That means that it could not find `@venue`.

Comment: You should be passing an :id parameter. Make sure you are passing thing by checkout your logs.

Comment: Thanks, thats got rid of the error but it's still creating a new form on adding an offer.

Comment: It's not creating a new form. It's the same form but you are editing it.

Comment: Can you conceptually explain what you want to do?

Comment: I thought I was explaining it badly as I wrote it. Essentially I want to visit the venues edit page and have a form to add offers to that venue. I can currently do this but the create offer form is duplicating with each new offer added. I just want one form to display and once an offer is added I want the one form to clear ready for a new offer to be added. I'll add a couple screenshots to my question.

Comment: It's still not changing, with each submit a new 'add new offer' form is appearing.

Comment: If you don't want it to go to the edit action then you need to change what happens if it is saved.

Comment: So in edit action. instead of ` redirect_to edit_venue_path(@venue)` you need ` redirect_to @venue`

Comment: Great stuff, I'll give that a go tomorrow morning thanks for the help!

Comment: NP, let me know if you have questions.