# Why am I getting a collection_select field for every option record in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, form-helpers, formbuilder

Thanks in advance! If you can help me solve this, it'll let me complete this project after two months of work. Here's the set-up for my Rails form:

- I've got two multiple select boxes. "waypoints" starts out without any options in it. "select1" has all of the options.
- I use buttons and javascript to move options from "select1" to "waypoints".
- "waypoints" is a [FormBuilder collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select).

For some reason using the code below,

- When creating a new record, "waypoints" does not appear in the view.
- When updating a record that already has waypoints saved in the database, the "waypoints" multiple select box repeats in the view. For example, if I have saved three addresses as waypoints in the database, I get three multiple select boxes on the screen, each with a different option highlighted. I'm wondering if it's related to this issue: [How can I stop a form repeating using fields_for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769185/how-can-i-stop-a-form-repeating-using-fields-for) Trying some related options, but still no luck.

**View**

*Note that this is a Rails 2 app I'm updating. That's why the form_for and fields_for don't have = signs.*

```
    <% form_for @newsavedmap, :html => { :id => 'createaMap' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>               
    <%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30 }%></p>
    <% f.fields_for :waypoints do |w| %>
    <%= w.collection_select :waypointaddress, @newsavedmap.waypoints, :waypointaddress, :waypoint_name, {}, { :multiple => true, :class => "mobile-waypoints-remove", :id =>"waypoints" } %>      
    <% end %>
    <select multiple id="select1">
    OPTIONS
    </select>
    JAVASCRIPT BUTTONS TO MOVE OPTIONS TO WAYPOINTS
    <% end %>
```

**Output from view for waypoint records that have been saved**

```
    <div>
    <select id="waypoints" multiple="multiple" name="newsavedmap[waypoints_attributes][0][waypointaddress][]">
    <option value="1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500" selected="selected">DC</option>
    <option value="350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118">NY</option>
    </select>     

    <input id="newsavedmap_waypoints_attributes_0_id" name="newsavedmap[waypoints_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="123">

    <select id="waypoints" multiple="multiple" name="newsavedmap[waypoints_attributes][1][waypointaddress][]">
    <option value="1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500">DC</option>
    <option value="350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118" selected="selected">NY</option>
    </select>     
    <input id="newsavedmap_waypoints_attributes_1_id" name="newsavedmap[waypoints_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden" value="124">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is coming from your use of fields_for in this context, which is usually used to display a set of fields for each instance of an associated record.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the quick response. :Waypoints is nested in :Newsavedmaps in a one-to-many relationship (A newsavedmap can have many waypoints.) How do you think I can keep this relationship without using fields_for? Is there a better way (I'm still very new to nested forms.)